# Check if an object exists in other objects' sub-objects within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

I have kind of this Array :

```
array = [
     {
      a:0, 
      b:{x:1,y:2} 
     },
     {
      c:0,
      b:{x:3,y:2}},
    ]
```

And I have a new object like this

```
{
 e:0, 
 b:{x:2,y:5}
}
```

I want to test whether the objects in `array` have the **same** **nested** `b object` or not, if so I'll push the new object there, if it already exists, I'll replace the whole object with the newer one.
Any help how could I achieve that please (Lodash, ES6..),
I'm using Typescript btw.

Comment: try to use extend in jquery - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: I'm not using Jquery ^^, you can check the tags there Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Amol B Lande `$.extend` is for plain **objects**, not arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method with your array to test if there's any matching `b` object with the searched object, your code will be:

```
function checkIfObjectExists(array, obj) {
  return array.some(function(element) {
    return (typeof obj.b === typeof element.b) && JSON.stringify(obj.b) === JSON.stringify(element.b);
  });
}
```

This is a working snippet:

```js
function checkIfObjectExists(array, obj) {
  return array.some(function(element) {
    return (typeof obj.b === typeof element.b) && JSON.stringify(obj.b) === JSON.stringify(element.b);
  });
}

array = [{
    a: 0,
    b: {
      x: 1,
      y: 2
    }
  },
  {
    c: 0,
    b: {
      x: 3,
      y: 2
    }
  },
];

var searched = {
  e: 0,
  b: {
    x: 2,
    y: 5
  }
};


//Check an existing userId
console.log(checkIfObjectExists(array, searched));

//Check a non existing userId
console.log(checkIfObjectExists(array, {
  a: 0,
  b: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2
  }
}));
```

Comment: Objects are compared by **reference**. So `obj.b=== element.b` always fails

Comment: I've edited the snippet and changed the `searched` sub-object so that it is the same sub-object of the first object in the array, and ran but it shows `false` ..

Comment: @hindmost well pointed out, I updtaed the answer to compare the String representation of objects.

Comment: Thank you for the smooth answer

Answer (score 1):

The following  IsExists() retun true if same object already exists and return false if same object not exists.

```
function IsExists(YourList,Object ) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < YourList.length; i++) {
            if (YourList[i].c === Object .c && YourList[i].b === Object .b) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

call you function like:

```
    var NewObject={
     e:0, 
     b:{x:2,y:5}
    }

if (!IsExists(array ,NewObject.b))
{
array .push(NewObject);
}
```

if the IsExists(array ,NewObject.b)return false then push this object into array

Comment: @abuabu try it.. this will helpful

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll through @chsdk 's answer , it looks smoother without loops , I cannot upvote yours since I do not have enough reputations..